# SMS Alert Message on Mobile Phone through Prometheus Alertmanager

Tags: linux, yaml, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We have Setup Prometheus in our environment with Node_exporter. We use AlertManager to send an email message to our team. We are able to receive the email.

We also try to configure the SMS in AlertManager so that we got an alert on our mobile phone if any services are down and resolved.

Could someone suggest how to do the configuration in Alertmanager for SMS API? We have an our Internal SMS API, and we need to integrate with the AlertManager to get the alerts on our mobile phone number.

AlertManager Configuration File

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 1m
  slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T01xxxxxxGD/B018ZXXXXXXXXF/Pwxe0xxxxxxxxxxxhiq'
  pagerduty_url: 'https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue'
route:
  receiver: 'smtp-local'
  routes:
    - match:
        severity: critical,warning
      receiver: 'slack-notifications'
      continue: true
    - match:
        severity: critical,warning
      receiver: 'web.hook'
      continue: true
    - match:
        severity: critical,warning
      receiver: 'pagerduty-notifications'
      continue: true
    - match:
        severity: critical,warning
      receiver: 'smtp-local'
      continue: true      
receivers:
  - name: 'smtp-local'
    email_configs:
    - to: 'xxx@xxx.com'
      from: 'xxx@xxx.com'
      smarthost: localhost:25
      require_tls: false
      send_resolved: true
  - name: 'slack-notifications'
    slack_configs:
    - channel: '#monitoring'
      send_resolved: true
      icon_url: https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462
      title: |-
        [{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] {{ .CommonLabels.alertname }} for {{ .CommonLabels.job }}
        {{- if gt (len .CommonLabels) (len .GroupLabels) -}}
          {{" "}}(
          {{- with .CommonLabels.Remove .GroupLabels.Names }}
            {{- range $index, $label := .SortedPairs -}}
              {{ if $index }}, {{ end }}
              {{- $label.Name }}="{{ $label.Value -}}"
            {{- end }}
          {{- end -}}
          )
        {{- end }}
      text: >-
        {{ range .Alerts -}}
        *Alert:* {{ .Annotations.title }}{{ if .Labels.severity }} - `{{ .Labels.severity }}`{{ end }}
      
        *Description:* {{ .Annotations.description }}
      
        *Details:*
          {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • *{{ .Name }}:* `{{ .Value }}`
          {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
  - name: 'web.hook'
    webhook_configs:
    - url: 'http://xxxxxxx:xxxx/xxxx?msisdn=xxxx&text=xxxxx.'
  - name: 'pagerduty-notifications'
    pagerduty_configs:
    - service_key: 3a560cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7c198
      send_resolved: true
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could configure the [Webhook receiver](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#webhook_config) to POST JSON representing the alert to an endpoint that either directly, or more likely proxies, to your SMS API. See the examples in the link to see how this has been achieved for other services.

You have a PagerDuty config. Could you not (also) have PagerDuty send you SMS [notifications](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/notifications#section-sms-notifications) too?

Comment: thanks, it was simple and it's worked for me with doing this:

`webhook_configs:
    - url: 'http://10.xx.xx.xx:8082/kundirun'`